# Truncating Old Data Points in LSTM Network?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a time series that I have turned into a supervised learning problem in order to train a LSTM network on, and I continue to add newer data points to my training set. However, as the time series gets longer and longer, it becomes more computationally expensive to train my network. Is there a technique to truncating old data points that might not have a significant impact on predicting the future? Is there literature that might support such a notion?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fit with a slice of the data: `slicedX = X[:,-50:]` and, if you have Y with length: `slicedY = Y[:,-50:]`.

In the examples I used a length containing the last 50 timesteps.

### What is the correct number of timesteps?

The answer lies within your own data. And only experimenting will tell how many steps the net needs to work in a satisfying way.